# Error while creating/updating Maven project in STS eclipse

Tags: eclipse

[image]

I have installed STS recently on Ubuntu system but i appears an error while create/update any maven project.

Can't understand what it says!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution by deleting .m2 directory :D